# Automatically authenticate using Linkedin's REST api

Tags: rest, windows-8, microsoft-metro, linkedin-api

I'm trying to build a win8 javascript app and automatically authenticate myself to show my linkedin info in the app.

However I've only been able to find info on how to authenticate a user manually (enter pass/user). I would like to make an automatic request as the "user" will always be me and send a request with my login token/info in it.

Is this possible?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Let's say you have a `LinkdInAuth` method that takes user and password as parameters. All you have to do is, on your default js:

```
ready: function (element, options) {
LinkdInAuth("yourUser","yourPass");
};
```

If you don't have that method, it is easily adaptable from the examples you find on the web.

Comment: -1 How does this answere the question? What do you mean with `default.js`, what is the `ready` function? Where is `LinkdInAuth` defined?

Comment: I'm not a fan of providing the whole code, but guidelines. Anyway, the `ready` function is defined in evey JS file related with an HTML page, inside the "namespace" definition.

The `LinkdInAuth` is pretty clear with "Lets say..." and "if you don't have that..."